# Laravel Routes onclick window.location doesn't work

Tags: laravel

Why doesnt this work?

```
<div class="bewinkel-img"
                 @if(!empty($content->category_id) && isset($website_category->category->group_url))
                    onclick='window.location = "{{URL::route(\"productv2.category\", $website_category->category->group_url.'/'.$website_category->category->complete_url) }}"'>

                 @elseif(!empty($content->category_group_id) && isset($website_category_group->url))
                    onclick='window.location = "{{URL::route("productv2.category", $website_category_group->url) }}"

                 @endif
                <div style="@if($content->height != "") width:100%; height:{{$content->height}}px; @else height:300px; @endif background-image: url('{!!cdn_asset($content->img)!!}')">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Error Message is as below:

> Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Change this line

```
onclick='window.location = "{{URL::route(\"productv2.category\", $website_category->category->group_url.'/'.$website_category->category->complete_url) }}"'>
```

To

```
onclick='window.location = "{{URL::route("productv2.category", $website_category->category->group_url.'/'.$website_category->category->complete_url) }}"'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick='window.location = "{{route('productv2.category', $website_category->category->group_url.'/'.$website_category->category->complete_url) }}"'>
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code as follows:

```
<div class="bewinkel-img"
         @if(!empty($content->category_id) && isset($website_category->category->group_url))
            onclick='window.location = "{{ route("productv2.category", $website_category->category->group_url . '/' . $website_category->category->complete_url) }}"'>
        @elseif(!empty($content->category_group_id) && isset($website_category_group->url))
            onclick='window.location = "{{ route("productv2.category", $website_category_group->url) }}"
        @endif
        <div
            style="
                @if($content->height != "")
                    width:100%;
                    height:{{$content->height}}px;
                @else
                    height:300px;
                @endif
                    background-image: url('{!! cdn_asset($content->img) !!}')
                "
        ></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remve quotes from url.

So, Change from

```
<div class="bewinkel-img"
                 @if(!empty($content->category_id) && isset($website_category->category->group_url))
                    onclick='window.location = "{{URL::route(\"productv2.category\", $website_category->category->group_url.'/'.$website_category->category->complete_url) }}"'>
```

To

```
<div class="bewinkel-img"
                 @if(!empty($content->category_id) && isset($website_category->category->group_url))
                    onclick='window.location = "{{URL::route("productv2.category", $website_category->category->group_url.'/'.$website_category->category->complete_url) }}"'>
```